# How to split a CSV file in two files with overlapping rows?

Tags: python, csv, split

I have a CSV file with, let's say, 16000 rows. I need to split it up in two separate files, but also need an overlap in the files of about 360 rows, so row 1-8360 in one file and row 8000-16000 in the other. Or 1-8000 and 7640-16000.

CSV file look like this:

```
Value          X             Y               Z
4.5234  -46.29753186    -440.4915915    -6291.285393
4.5261  -30.89639381    -441.8390165    -6291.285393
4.5289  -15.45761327    -442.6481287    -6291.285393
4.5318   0              -442.9179423    -6291.285393
```

I have used this code in Python 3 to split the file, but I'm unable to get the overlap I want:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvfile = f.readlines()

linesPerFile = 8000
filename = 1

for i in range(0,len(csvfile),linesPerFile+):
    with open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+') as f:
        if filename > 1: # this is the second or later file, we need to write the
            f.write(csvfile[0]) # header again if 2nd.... file
        f.writelines(csvfile[i:i+linesPerFile])
    filename += 1
```

And tried to modify it like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(csvfile),linesPerFile+360):
```

and

```
f.writelines(csvfile[360-i:i+linesPerFile])
```

but I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy with Pandas [CSV](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/search.html?q=csv&check_keywords=yes&area=default) and [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

```
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_csv('source_file.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.np.random.randn(16000, 5))

df.iloc[:8360].to_csv('file_1.csv')
df.iloc[8000:].to_csv('file_2.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have got a more elegant answer using Pandas. You could consider below if don't like to install modules.

```
def write_files(input_file, file1, file2, file1_end_line_no, file2_end_line_no):

    # Open all 3 file handles
    with open(input_file) as csv_in, open(file1, 'w') as ff, open(file2, 'w') as sf:

        # Process headers
        header = next(csv_in)
        header = ','.join(header.split()) 
        ff.write(header + '\n')
        sf.write(header + '\n')

        for index, line in enumerate(csv_in):
            line_content = ','.join(line.split())   # 4.5234  -46.29753186    -440.4915915    -6291.285393 => 4.5234,-46.29753186,-440.4915915,-6291.285393

            if index <= file1_end_line_no:           # Check if index is less than or equals first file's max index
                ff.write(line_content + '\n')

            if index >= file2_end_line_no:          # Check if index is greater than or equals second file's max index
                sf.write(line_content + '\n')
```

Sample Run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_file = 'csvfile.csv'
    write_files(
        in_file,
        '1.txt', 
        '2.txt', 
        2, 
        2
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
for i in range(0,len(csvfile),linesPerFile+):
    init = i
    with open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+') as f:
        if filename > 1: # this is the second or later file, we need to write the
            f.write(csvfile[0]) # header again if 2nd.... file
            init = i - 360
        f.writelines(csvfile[init:i+linesPerFile+1])
    filename += 1
```

Is this what you are looking for? Please upload a test file if it doesn't so we can provide a better answer :-)